# How to enable high speed Bluetooth (3.0+HS or 4.0) in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

So I have a BT client and a server application on two Bluetooth 4.0 android phones. The server waits for a connection via

```
BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(SDP_NAME, UUID.fromString(SDP_UUID));
```

and the client connects to it via

```
socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(SDP_UUID));
```

Then, using a AsyncTask, I am sending data in an endless loop from the client to the server.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
outputStream.write(buffer);
```

I calculated the speed and only got around 230KByte/s, which is exactly the 2,1 MBit/s that Bluetooth EDR offers. How to I send the data via Bluetooth HS (24 MBit/s)?

Comment: This answer seems very relevant: https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-companies-that-offer-embedded-chips-+-development-kits-that-use-Bluetooth-HS

Answer (score 3):

BT 3.0+HS is a scheme where the high rates are achieved by actually using Wifi physical layer.  So it only works if you have the right kind of BT/Wifi combo chips that support it, which isn't really very common.  Having a 4.0 device does not mean it does 3.0+HS, it just means it can do BT Low Energy, which is low data rate.

Comment: Ok, I thought 3.0+HS got included in [4.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_v4.0), just like EDR got included in 3.0. I haven't seen a 4.0 EDR or 4.0+HS label I think. Still, I tested with a Samsung Galaxy S3, which is [supposed to have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices#Smartphones) Bluetooth Highspeed. So how do I use the BT 4.0+HS of the Galaxy S3?

Comment: Actually, having a BT 4.0 doesn't mean you automagically have BLE, because it's optional feature. And most random "4.0" devices don't support BLE. They also don't support HS as we figured. That means quite a bunch of "4.0" and "3.0" devices are on the level of BT 2.1. Actually, on the level of 2.0, because quite a few devices don't properly support Secure Simple Pairing (and SSP is *required* to not have your device and data p0wned). Welcome to wonderful world of technical marketing.

Comment: "only works if you have the right kind of BT/Wifi combo chips that support it" - actually, I used to think just like that. But thought occurred to me: why exactly it's gotta be like that? What standard says is that BT HS uses WiFi protocol. BT & WiFi radios are already largely the same, just add DSSS modulation to BT chip, and format packets with WiFi headers. *That*'s how it really should work, nothing else realistically will.

Comment: @pfalcon, BT & WiFi are only "largely the same" at a very coarse level.  Real BT / WiFi radios in products are extremely optimized to match the requirements of each.  There are major differences, mainly that WiFi is wider bandwidth and requires much higher symbol rates.  Also optimal receiver architectures are different.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that Google has not opened up the API's required to drive the function built in the 4.0 chips. Since the functionality works on laptops and various Windows OS's maybe the mobile Window OS is closer or capable of operating such with a software patch. I think the priority for Google is to work on low battery before HS.

Also I think that Wireless operators were not keen on allowing high speed tethering for free, which has killed the software development efforts.