# Bluetooth 3.0 HS support in Android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I did not find any information about `Bluetooth 3.0 HS` support in `Android`. Is there any `API` for that? Is it supported at all?

I have an `Android-based (4.1.2 with BlueZ stack)` device with hardware support for `Bluetooth 3.0 HS`. I am trying to investigate how much effort need to be done to add support of `Bluetooth 3.0 HS` to `Android` + `BlueZ`. May be it is better to switch to newer `Android` and `Bluetooth stack (bluedroid)`?

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382241/how-to-enable-high-speed-bluetooth-3-0hs-or-4-0-in-android

Comment: Yep, I've seen that post and it is still unclear to me whether Android has API for enabling 3.0 HS or if any roadmap exists.

Comment: Don't be fooled into thinking that Bluedroid is a newer or better stack than BlueZ.  BlueZ is still very active, and there's even projects that show how to use BlueZ in the latest versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not have an API specifically for Bluetooth 3.0 or even just BLE. It provides a basic BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener API and several methods for their own Bluetooth Class, but in every case they abstract away hardware details, I would try for a newer open-source stack if possible, but none that I have seen appear to allow you to access the speed protocols, not sure why you wish to manipulate them directly, as long as the standard libraries compile to functioning Bluetooth on your device.